# where we sould dispatch use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

Tags: laravel-8

I'm a beginner with laravel
in email verification in laravel docs, something is not clear for me can anyone help me.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification

> If you are manually implementing registration within your application
> instead of using a starter kit, you should ensure that you are
> dispatching the Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered event after a user's
> registration is successful:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
>
> event(new Registered($user));
> ```

where we should ensure that we are dispatching

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

event(new Registered($user));
```

can anyone explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

You may attach listeners to these events in your application's `EventServiceProvider` (from http://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#events):

```
protected $listen = [
    'user.registered' => ['App\Handlers\Events\RegisterEvents@userRegistered'],
],
```

In your logic:

```
if($user = User::create($request->all())) {
    app('event')->fire('user.registered', $user);
}
```

Implement RegisterEvents:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\User;

class RegisterEvents {

    public function userRegistered(User $user)
    {
      // get an action with user
    }

}
```